# AR.js - GeoAR - Why is the gps-camera not a registered component of the a-camera?

Tags: angular, cordova, ar.js

Usage: ar.js - geo Ar with Angular & Cordova

First I created a min site (without Angular) based on the ar.js example code and ported it to cordova -> evertything works fine.

Then I copied the code into a fresh Angular App and all markers are glued to the camera.

After some debugging I noticed, that in the component registration of `gps-entity-place` the component `gps-camera` is not registered on the camera.

```js
      var camera = document.querySelector('a-camera, [camera]');
      if (camera.components['gps-camera'] === undefined) {
        return;  // Undefined, so it returns here...
      }
```

But it should be there. The complete scene is

```html
<a-scene
  cursor='rayOrigin: mouse; fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 0;'
  raycaster="objects: [gps-entity-place];"
  vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
  embedded
  arjs='sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth:1280; sourceHeight:960; displayWidth: 1280; displayHeight: 960; debugUIEnabled: false;'>

  <a-camera gps-camera="minDistance: 20;" rotation-reader>
  </a-camera>

  <a-image
    gps-entity-place="latitude: 51.97250529; longitude: 10.96151222;"
    name="test"
    scale="20, 20"
    alpha-test="0.5"
    src="./assets/map-marker.png"
  ></a-image>
</a-scene>
```

`aframe.js` and `aframe-ar.js` are loaded in the `<head>`
`schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` is set in the Angular module.

Query of the camera components: `document.querySelector('a-camera, [camera]').components`

- `camera`
- `look-controls`
- `position`
- `rotation`
- `wasd-controls`
- ... but no gps-camera

What could be the reason for this behaviour? Where else can I debug to find the reason?